# LHS condition about duration how I can

Tags: jboss, drools, rule-engine, rule, drools-fusion

In our company we are evaluate Drools as framework for our products.
For that I am trying some experiments and *obviously* I am now **overwhelmed** by lot of problems.
For example I don't know how make condition on duration of an event.
I don't know if there is something similar to

```
.. 
when
 Event( some conditions, duration > 1h)
then
...
```

Thank very much in advanced

Comment: Please describe the `Event` class, and what it is supposed to do.

Comment: It will be used to mark changes in an environment as for example "presence detected" or similar. Some of these event has to be retracted when event duration is more than a defined amount of time. In the following my event class in short
`//.. jAXB annotationspublic class Event
    implements Serializable, Equals, HashCode, ToString
{...
    protected EventType type;  //i.e. PRESSURE_ACTIVATED, PRESENCE...
    protected List<ESubject> subjects; //i.e. ERSON, ROOM ...
    protected Long duration;
    protected Long occurred;
...get and setter returning default values in case of null`

Answer (score 0):

Duration is member like any other on your event class. When you declare your event, you tell it which member is the duration like so:

```
declare VoiceCall
  @role( event )
  @timestamp( callDateTime )
  @duration( callDuration )
end
```

Duration is in milliseconds, so you would reason against it in a rule like so:

```
rule "Call Longer Than One Hour"
  when
    VoiceCall( callDuration > 3600000 ) // 1000*60*60
  then
    ...
end
```

The Drools Fusion [manual](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.4.0.Beta2/drools-fusion-docs/html_single/#d0e289) describes this pretty clearly (in fact, my example event declaration is taken directly from it).